# Not using SD card permissions in an Android app, but still it is being asked when installing

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

I have developed an application which uses following permissions.

1. CALL_PHONE
2. INTERNET
3. ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

I have not accessed external storage in the entire app, but it is still asking for storage permissions when installing on device. Is the issue with code or device or Android?

#### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nirajburde.free"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/My_Theme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NumberList"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label=""
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post the permission you are setting in your manifest here. and we cannot tell if the problem is with your code unless we see some code

Comment: @NirajBurde : You are targeting `minSdkVersion="3"`. Earlier versions of the Android APIs request the permission to access external storage implicitly (without you requesting it explicitly in the manifest). This is a known issue and was changed in a later version of the API but I can't remember which version.

Comment: @Squonk : Thanks Squonk, I never thought that this could be the reason. Can I change it to later version, because anyways I'm focusing on API 8 ?

Comment: @NirajBurde : Yes, if you target API 8 and set minSdkVersion also to 8, then the external storage permission will no longer be requested implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Before [Android DONUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT), the SDK automatically adds [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and [`READ_PHONE_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) to your app's permissions, hence you can target your app to SDK 1.6 or newer ones to avoid that.